# How time executing depends of increasing of number of threads with using OpenMP library?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, time, openmp

**Increasing number of threads increase the time of loop execution rather decrease it.**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define n 4

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE * file1 = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (file1 == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    int matrix[n][n];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
            fprintf(file1, "%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(file1, "\n");
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int min;
    double start;
    double end;
```

*Starting cout the time of loop*

```
    start = omp_get_wtime();

// in num_threads I've changed the number of threads 
// and investigate a problem of increasing the time

#pragma omp parallel for private (i, j, min) reduction(+:sum)       num_threads(4) 
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            min = INT_MAX;
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if(matrix[j][i] < min){
                    min = matrix[j][i];
                    }
            }
            sum += min; // sum of min numbers of each column
        }
end = omp_get_wtime();

printf("Time: %lf\n", end - start);

printf("Min sum of matrix = %d", sum);
fclose(file1);
return 0;
}
```

---

4 threads 
Time: 0.000930 
3 threads  
Time: 0.000356 
2 threads 
Time: 0.000533 
1 thread 
Time: 0.000008

My CPU has 4 threads.

Comment: For each thread, the OS needs to schedule the execution of the thread.  The more threads, the more time the OS spends with the scheduling.  Also, there is no guarantee that a thread will be the only program executed by a CPU core.  Worst case, all threads are executed on the same core.  Not to mention the resource sharing contingencies.

Comment: Your threads need to have significant execution time.  A thread that finishes before all the other threads are created may not be worthwhile as a thread.

Comment: If you are using a GPU, the OS needs to download the code to a GPU core, which takes time.  The OS then needs to tell the GPU to run the thread.  At some point the GPU needs to interrupt the OS and let the OS know that the thread is finished.  The OS needs to fetch any results from the GPU.  Multiply this overhead by each additional thread.

Comment: BTW, thread management has no connection to the language, C, C++ or Pascal.  The OS is executing a language agnostic executable and language agnostic threads.  The program could be written in Ada as well.

Comment: You benchmarking algorithm needs modification.  The `fprint` will be a bottleneck and cause resource sharing among the threads.  One thread has to wait for the thread using the file to finish before it can start or continue.  In general file I/O is more of a bottleneck than thread maintenance.  The time spent in each I/O transaction may not be constant either.

Comment: Hense, it is normal that time is increasing? I thought that it contradicts with using multithreading in programs.

Comment: Time may increase.  See may above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very small problem (4x4) and you are timing thread creation. I don't expect the parallelism to help much at this scale anyway (since just the cost of waking the threads and then synchronizing them again at the end of the parallel will be hugely larger than the work you are trying to do), but you can remove the cost of creating the thread pool from your measurement by adding a

`#pragma omp parallel
    ;`

before the timed region.

And, please, please, please, don't force the number of threads. Use the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` envirable.